# Restriction on associatedtype to an Array

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol with an associatedtype and I made some of my classes conform to it:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func myFunction()-> MyType
}

struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var myVar: Int
}

class MyClass1: MyProtocol {
    func myFunction()-> [MyStruct]? {
        return [MyStruct(myVar: 1)]
    }
}

class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    func myFunction()-> Int? {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a protocol that can only be applied to an object that is conform to `MyProtocol` **and** its associatedtype is an **array of Codable** like so:

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: [Codable] {}
```

However I get an error:

> Type 'Self.MyType' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type '[Codable]' (aka 'Array<Decodable & Encodable>')

How can I get around this problem and apply my restriction?

---

*Note: I get the same error when trying to restrict with any kind of Array, but works fine with other types:*

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: [Int] {} 
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: Array<Any> {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Array` is not a protocol, it's a struct:

```
@frozen struct Array<Element>
```

You can try to conform to `Sequence` instead:

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: Sequence, MyType.Element: Codable {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works fine. However since the Array is optional I got another error (from Optional this time). I had to add `protocol OptionalProtocol { associatedtype WrappedType }` and `extension Optional: OptionalProtocol { typealias WrappedType = Wrapped }` so that the final (long) conformance that works is: `protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType: OptionalProtocol, MyType.WrappedType: Sequence, MyType.WrappedType.Element: Codable {}`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use '==' to make associatedType constraints, replace yours instead of:

```
protocol MyProtocolCodable where Self: MyProtocol, MyType == [Codable] {}
```

Comment: This requires `MyStruct` to be equivalent to `Codable`.

Comment: Emm. Your answer is better!